# With Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 7.0.8 NuGet packages, scaffold-dbcontext doesn't seem to work with Visual Basic projects

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022

When I try to `scaffold-dbcontext` in my Visual Basic 2022 project, I get an error

> Project language 'VB' is not supported by the built-in service IModelCodeGenerator. You can try looking for an additional NuGet package that supports this language; move your DbContext type to a C# class library referenced by this project, or manually implement and register the design-time service for the programming language.

I have tried using version 6.0.19 of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sql`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget packages but the problem is not solved

Answer (score 2):

> **Other programming languages**
>
> The EF Core packages published by Microsoft scaffold C# code. However, the underlying scaffolding system
> supports a plugin model for scaffolding to other languages. This
> plugin model is used by various community-run projects, for example:
>
> EntityFrameworkCore.VisualBasic provides support for Visual Basic
> EFCore.FSharp provides support for F#

[Scaffolding (Reverse Engineering) - Other programming languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=vs#other-programming-languages)